# Haskell - Use induction to prove an implication

Tags: haskell, theorem-proving, induction, implication

I've to prove by induction that

```
no f xs ==> null (filter f xs)
```

Where :

```
filter p []    = []
filter p (x:xs) 
  | p x        = x : filter p xs
  | otherwise  = filter p xs

null [] = True; null _ = False 

no p [] = True
no p (x:xs)
  | p x = False
  | otherwise = no p xs

Logic implication:
True ==> False = False
_    ==> _     = True
```

So, I've supposed that the followings are my assumption and my claim:

```
Assumption: no f xs ==> null (filter f xs)
Claim: no f (x:xs) ==> null (filter f (x:xs))
```

And I started to try to prove the base case (the empty list):

```
no f [] ==> null (filter f [])
== {- Filter.1, filter p [] = [] -}
no f [] ==> null ([])
== {- No.1,  no p [] = True-}
True ==> null ([])
== {- Null.1, null [] = True -}
True ==> True
```

But I'm not sure it is correct, because I've proved that they are both True and not that if the left part is True and the second part is False, then the implication is False (that is the definition of ==>).
Is this correct?
How can I go on with the proof?
I don't clearly get how can I use induction to prove an implication...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you've done on the base case is correct, since your "implication" is also a Haskell function. So, when you use the empty list for xs in the base case, that's ok.

Comment: It's unnecessary to even examine `no f []`. We know, just by expanding the definitions, that `null (filter f []) = null [] = True` is True. You can proceed immediately to proving your inductive case!

Comment: "If the second part is False". You've just proved that the second part is in fact True. Therefore if the second part is False, then anything at all is True.

Comment: Arriving at `True ==> True` is a correct proof of `no f [] ==> null (filter f [])` because some statement is said to be proved if it is equivalent to `True` and `True ==> True` is trivially `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete proof. Later, when I have a bit more of time, I'll prove this on Agda or Idris and post the code here.

Proof by induction over `xs`.

Case `xs = []`:

```
no f [] ==> null (filter f [])
== {- Filter.1, filter p [] = [] -}
no f [] ==> null ([])
== {- No.1,  no p [] = True-}
True ==> null ([])
== {- Null.1, null [] = True -}
True ==> True
```

Case `xs = y : ys`. Suppose that `no f ys == null (filter f ys)`. Consider the following cases:

Case `f y == True`:

```
no f (y : ys) ==> null (filter f (y : ys))
== {- no - f y == True -}
False ==> null (filter f (y : ys))
== 
True
```

Case `f y == False`:

```
no f (y : ys) ==> null (filter f (y : ys))
=={- By definition of filter and no -}
no f ys ==> null (filter f ys)
== {By I.H.}
True
```

Which finishes the proof.